# How of to change font size for every nodes in tikzcd?

Tags: tikz-cd

How of to change font size for every nodes in tikzcd?

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{tikz-cd} 
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, matrix} 
\tikzcdset{every label/.append style = {scale=0.6,yshift=0.2ex}} 
\begin{document} 
\[\begin{tikzcd} 0\rar & \mathrm{Hom}_R(L, E) \arrow{r}{\mathrm{Hom}\!(\!\beta\!, \mathrm{id}\!_E\!)} & \mathrm{Hom}_R(N, E) \arrow{r}{\mathrm{Hom}(\alpha, \mathrm{id}_E)} & \mathrm{Hom}_R(M, E) \end{tikzcd}\] 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the Ti*k*Z `cd` is a Ti*k*Z `matrix`, you could use `every matrix/.append style={nodes={font=...}}`.

I would also leave out all those `\!` in the first label.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{tikz-cd} 
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, matrix} 
\tikzcdset{every label/.append style = {scale=0.6,yshift=0.6ex},
every matrix/.append style={nodes={font=\small}}
} 
\begin{document} 
\[\begin{tikzcd} 0\rar & \mathrm{Hom}_R(L, E) \arrow{r}{\mathrm{Hom}(\beta, \mathrm{id}_E)} & \mathrm{Hom}_R(N, E) \arrow{r}{\mathrm{Hom}(\alpha, \mathrm{id}_E)} & \mathrm{Hom}_R(M, E) \end{tikzcd}\] 
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit:*
As marmot pointed out, there is also the key `cells=<options>` which appends `<options>` to the style `every cell`, which, in turn, by default contains the following:

```
/tikz/shape=asymmetrical rectangle,
/tikz/inner xsep=1ex,
/tikz/inner ysep=0.85ex
```

See the [tikzcd package documentation](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-cd/tikz-cd-doc.pdf), Section 2.1 General options.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{tikz-cd} 
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, matrix} 
\tikzcdset{
    every label/.append style = {scale=0.6,yshift=0.6ex},
    cells={nodes={font=\small}}
    } 
\begin{document} 
\[
\begin{tikzcd} 
0\rar & \mathrm{Hom}_R(L, E) \arrow{r}{\mathrm{Hom}(\beta, \mathrm{id}_E)} & \mathrm{Hom}_R(N, E) \arrow{r}{\mathrm{Hom}(\alpha, \mathrm{id}_E)} & \mathrm{Hom}_R(M, E) 
\end{tikzcd}
\] 
\end{document}
```

The result is the same as before.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{tikz-cd} 
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, matrix} 
\tikzcdset{every label/.append style = {scale=0.6,yshift=0.2ex},
    nodes={font=\footnotesize}} 
\begin{document} 
\[\begin{tikzcd} 0\rar & \mathrm{Hom}_R(L, E) \arrow{r}{\mathrm{Hom}\!(\!\beta\!, \mathrm{id}\!_E\!)} & \mathrm{Hom}_R(N, E) \arrow{r}{\mathrm{Hom}(\alpha, \mathrm{id}_E)} & \mathrm{Hom}_R(M, E) \end{tikzcd}\] 
\end{document}
```

Btw how can readers read your supertiny text? I can't read it.

Comment: I undeleted this answer [as requested by CarLaTeX](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/50348840#50348840)